# Align Bootstrap panel to the Right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I want to align my right panel until the end. Do I need to add something to the CSS?

```
<div class="row flex">

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-no-border">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <p>
                        <strong>Smart XXXXX Europe Limited (XXXX Branch) </strong><br />
                        Address  <br>
                        Address  <br>
                        Address  <br>
                        Address  <br>
                        customer.relations@company.com<br>
                        www.comapny.com<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 text-right">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-no-border">
                @*<div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Mr. John Ryan</h4>
                    </div>*@
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                        <strong>Mr. John Ryan</strong><br />
                        36 Praed street <br>
                        XXXX, XXXXXX<br>
                        XXXXXX<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex, .flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

.panel {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-content:stretch; 
}

.panel-body {
   display: flex;
   flex-grow:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `justify-content: flex-end` to the parent of the panel:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2 text-right your-class">

.your-class {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/dsg1qHNopH

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap divs and then add `padding-right= 0px;` to second div.

see [working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/oqv21a96/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/nzLsedob/`
```

check out here
I hope this is the answer you want.